# org.Apache.Jasper.JasperException on JSP page

Tags: java, jsp

I'm given a JasperException at line 27 of this code, that is the second if that checks chkProgr. The three chk strings come from checkboxes.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Show input</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            String name = (String) request.getAttribute("name");
            String surname = (String) request.getAttribute("surname");
            String tel = (String) request.getAttribute("tel");
            String email = (String) request.getAttribute("email");
            String chkTelec = (String) request.getAttribute("chkTelec");
            String chkProgr = (String) request.getAttribute("chkProgr");
            String chkRobot = (String) request.getAttribute("chkRobot");            
        %>
        Name: <%=name%> <br />
        Surname: <%=surname%> <br />
        tel: <%=tel%> <br />
        email: <%=email%> <br />
        You chose these courses:
        <% if (!chkTelec.equals("null")) { %>
            Telecommunications <br />
        <% } if (!chkProgr.equals("null")) { %>
            Programming <br />
        <% } if (!chkRobot.equals("null")) { %>
            Robotics
        <% } %>
    </body>
</html>
```

On the error page there's also a NullPointerException under "Root cause", don't know if that can help.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I did check, there was a typo and I fixed it but the problem still persists.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /showInput.jsp at line 25
22:         You chose these courses:
23:         <% if (!chkTelec.equals("null")) { %>
24:             Telecommunications <br />
25:         <% } if (!chkProgr.equals("null")) { %>
26:             Programming <br />
27:         <% } if (!chkRobot.equals("null")) { %>
28:             Robotics


Stacktrace:
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        Servlets.conveyInput.processRequest(conveyInput.java:34)
        Servlets.conveyInput.doPost(conveyInput.java:63)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
        org.apache.jsp.showInput_jsp._jspService(showInput_jsp.java:126)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        Servlets.conveyInput.processRequest(conveyInput.java:34)
        Servlets.conveyInput.doPost(conveyInput.java:63)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Add your console log for exception.

Comment: Check for any typo in `chk` Strings.